# How to keep transient window on top in GTK+

Tags: gtk

I am porting a large (100+ files) 8 year old GTK+ application from Red Hat 2.4 to Ubuntu Lucid. It's a full screen application for an industrial control panel, the operator is not able to access the underlying OS.

It has various popups (eg a touch keyboard) which can appear in front of the main application. However, when I compile and run it on Ubuntu Lucid the popups remain hidden behind the main screen.

This program which uses the same GTK+ calls as the application demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *mainwindow;
    GtkWidget *popwindow;
    GtkWidget *label;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    mainwindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow), FALSE);
    gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow));
    gtk_widget_show_all(mainwindow);

    popwindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_keep_above(GTK_WINDOW(popwindow), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(popwindow), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW (popwindow), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(popwindow), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_position( GTK_WINDOW (popwindow), (GtkWindowPosition)GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(popwindow),GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow));

    label = gtk_label_new(g_strdup_printf ("My GTK version is %d.%d.%d", gtk_major_version, gtk_minor_version, gtk_micro_version));
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(popwindow), label);
    gtk_widget_show(label);
    gtk_widget_show(popwindow);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

The popup remains hidden, and it can only be seen if you Alt-Tab to a different window (not the mainwindow).
If I remove the call to gtk_window_set_transient_for() then the popup does appear, but the desktop panel also appears giving access to the underlying operating system.

Is there any way to get the desired behavior? 
Ubuntu Lucid uses GTK+ 2.20.1

Thanks for any help

Richard

Comment: Have you tried creating the popup window with GTK_WINDOW_POPUP?

Comment: I had been put off using GTK_WINDOW_POPUP by the documentation here http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkWindowType but I just tried it and it seems to work fine for me - thanks!

Comment: Denying access by keeping windows on top is a very weak security measure. You should instead not start a desktop at all, but letting your application be the only X application running. For a full screen interface I would also not work with popup windows, but use stack and overlay widgets to do everything in a single window.

Answer (score 3):

Use [gtk_window_present()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-present) to actually raise the popup in the stacking order:

```
gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (popwindow));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that. It doesn't work, my popup is still behind the mainwindow

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is on purpose: fullscreen windows are always on top, but that depends on your window manager.

https://answers.launchpad.net/awn/+question/126562

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-perl-list/2007-April/msg00071.html

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2003-November/msg00059.html

Answer (score 1):

As yet stated, this really depends on the window manager: your code works on my system (xfwm).

Instead of hiding stuff, I suggest to disable it. Although the panel could be covered by a window, the shortcuts (and whatever needed by that panel) will be still enabled. This is a matter of writing a custom [.xinitrc](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_X11/Starting_Sessions) in the default user home directory, for example:

```
#! /bin/sh
openbox &
myapplication
shutdown -h
```

This has the additional benefit of avoiding the desktop baggage and shutdown the system after closing myapplication.

Additional note: GTK+2 itself mimics a (**very primitive**) window manager, so you can try to start *myapplication* directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [set_keep_above()](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-keep-above).

Example (Python):

```
# Create dialog 
d = gtk.Dialog("RT600", buttons=("OK",True,"Cancel",False))

# Centering dialog
d.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

# Keep dialog above main window !
d.set_keep_above(True)

# run the dialog
result = d.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-type-hint)

```
gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW(popwindow), GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DIALOG)
```

[This](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-type-hint) should keep the popwindow above mainwindow!

Answer (score 0):

Simply with

```
gtk_window_set_keep_above(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
```